# Record Skype voice call in iPhone

Tags: ios, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Is it possible to record Skype call in iPhone by using Skype business iOS sdk or any other way. If possible then help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via the Skype for business iOS SDK.